# What should be commented in an ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

Here is the list of points that is interesting for me.

**Should we put comments on our controller's action methods?**

The reason is why I am asking this is because the action methods are very self explanatory, and the best comment I can think of would be something like "Returns the view for Products." Seems to cause mess and doesn't feel much helpful.

**Should we have any comments in the Views?**

When visual studio generates action methods it automatically puts in comments like ...

> ```
>     //
>     // GET: /Products/
> ```
>
> ... **is that ^ good practice?**

**Any advises/recommendations on commenting/documenting ASP.NET MVC applications?**

I did google for information about this but didn't find anything helpful that's why I am asking here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually get rid of those auto-generated comments. I'd say you should follow the same principles with MVC code that you follow with regular code:

- If the purpose and function of a method is obvious from its name, don't bother commenting it.
- If it's obvious what a line of code is doing and why, don't bother commenting it.
- If there's a possibility that the method will have expectations that aren't immediately obvious, or may have less-than-obvious secondary consequences, comment it.
- If it's not obvious *what* a line of code is doing, change the code to be more clear.
- If it's not obvious *why* you're doing what you're doing, add a comment.

Answer (score 5):

My practice is to never comment something unless it absolutely needs comments. Your code should be so easy to read, comments are unnecesary. If you find yourself needing to write a comment, that's a sign that perhaps you can simplify what you're doing.

Comment: there are times when you write code to workaround some third party (even MVC) limitation, in those cases, comments are useful)